# What does "cabin class" mean when describing GA aircraft?

Tags: general-aviation

Does it mean that there's a door with stairs? Or pressurized? Or that the seats are arranged a certain way?

Comment: Where did you see this?

Comment: “Cabin Class” is a very common term to describe larger general aviation aircraft. I don’t think there is an official definition. Most have 6-8 seats in a “club seating” arrangement. Most are pressurized with an air-stair door, but I don’t believe these items are required in order to be called “Cabin Class”.

Comment: I would say Cabin Class implies a bulkhead of some type separating the cockpit from the cabin, so that they are two separate compartments.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

the classic definition is a plane whose fuselage is wide enough to allow access to the rearmost seats via a gap or aisle between the forward seats. It also allows the pilot to get into the cockpit through the same boarding door that the passengers use, by climbing in between the front seats and stepping over the middle console.